# Passing csv file as command like argument in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I can't for the life of me think of a way to do this. I've previously worked with importing csv files into js files, but for this challenge I've got to create a js file that executable from a shell with the data file passed as input.

Any ideas how can this be done?

#### ~The challenge description~

The program must be executable from a shell and take the CSV file as input. For example:

```
node score_calculator.js data.csv
```

Comment: Where do you get stuck ?

Comment: Well I'm fine writing the js file, but I'm not sure how data.csv will be passed to the js file

Comment: @user6456392 you should change your question to **passing csv file as command like argument in nodeJs**

Comment: Thanks @UsmanRana for the title suggestion . I've updated it!

Comment: @user6456392 you can accept and upvote the answer if this resolved your query :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the file path as command line argument when running your `nodejs` app like

```
node myScript.js pathToCsvFile
```

Now you'll have to get this path in your code as

```
var filePath = process.argv[2];
```

Now you can use this path to read your file as

```
   fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
     if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
 });
```

Read more about file handling in `nodejs` [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to figure out how to pass and read parameters

You could do `node score_calculator.js data.csv`

then in your js

```
const csv = process.argv[2];
```

However. If you are passing in parameters I would recommend using [minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist) then you can do

```
node score_calculator.js --file=data.csv
```

And you js file would be

```
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
const csv = argv.file;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but for the challenge I can't use any external modules. Minimist does seem really useful though 